# Converse of Legendre's Theorem

Tags: number-theory

Let a R b denote that a = $r^2$ (b) for some integer r.

$ax^2 + by^2 = z^2$ has a nontrivial rational solution with a,b positive squarefree integers iff

(i) a R b

(ii) b R a

(iii) -$\frac{ab}{d^2}$ R d where d = gcd(a,b)

This is a variant of Legendre's Theorem that my text proves. The text has a detailed proof that is the three conditions are met, then the $ax^2 + by^2 = z^2$ has a nontrivial rational solution. However, the converse is simply assumed without discussion, although at least to me it does not seem intuitive.

If some solution (x, y, z) exists, then I see that, for example, a = ($\frac{z}{x})^2$ (mod b), but how do we know that $\frac{z}{x}$ is an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Q}^3$ is a solution to $ax^2 + by^2 = z^2$.  Let $\ell$ be the lcm of the denominators of $x,y,z$.  By multiplying through by $\ell^2$ in the equation and replacing $(x,y,z)$ by $(\ell x, \ell y, \ell z)$, we may assume that $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Furthermore, since we multiply by the *least* common multiple, we can take $x,y,z$ to be relatively prime, i.e., $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$.

As you point out, if $x$ is invertible mod $b$, then we have $a = (z/x)^2 \pmod{b}$, so $aRb$.  Thus it suffices to show that $\gcd(x,b) = 1$.  Suppose to the contrary that $\gcd(x,b) \neq 1$.  Then $p \mid \gcd(x,b)$ for some prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $p \mid x$ and $p \mid b$.  Since $ax^2 + by^2 = z^2$, then $p \mid z^2$, so $p \mid z$.  But we assumed that $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$, so this is a contradiction.